# Is there any precedent of the Russian president skipping a debate during the presidential elections?

Tags: russian-federation

> The Kremlin confirmed Tuesday that President Vladimir Putin will not
> take the stage to debate his rivals in Russia's March presidential
> election.
>
> “Everyone can see Putin’s statements on all aspects of Russians’ lives
> on a virtually daily basis,” Kremlin spokesman Dmitry Peskov told
> reporters.
>
> He added that Putin “fundamentally differs” from all other candidates
> because of his “very busy presidential schedule.”
>
> Russia’s Central Election Commission (CEC) officially registered four
> candidates for the March presidential race — Putin, Leonid Slutsky of
> the far-right Liberal Democratic Party, Nikolai Kharitonov of the
> Communist Party and Vladislav Davankov of the New People party.

https://www.themoscowtimes.com/2024/02/13/putin-to-skip-presidential-debates-kremlin-says-a84063

Is there any precedent of the Russian president skipping a debate during the presidential elections? The Moscow Times reported that current Russian president Vladimir Putin would not take the stage to debate his rivals in Russia's March presidential elections. I was wondering if there was any precedent for such a move in Russia's history.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Vladimir Putin has never participated in a Presidential election debate -- not in 1991, 1996, 2000, 2004, 2008, 2012, 2018 or 2024. (Although in all fairness he wasn't a candidate in 1991, 1996, or, in theory, 2008).

Comment: 1991 and 1996 is a bit of a stretch - he was neither a candidate, nor an important political figure back then.

Comment: That is a bit tongue in cheek but it's also a reminder that there have been only two Presidential elections before Putin (and 2008 with a seat warmer) so there's not much precedence for anything other than Putin.

Comment: Apart from that the answer is correct. +1