# Did Yeltsin participate in formal debates against other candidates for the Russian presidency?

Tags: russian-federation, presidential-election, media, debate, incumbency

Somewhat related to [this Q](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/84728/is-there-any-precedent-of-the-russian-president-skipping-a-debate-during-the-pre), I found that Yeltsin had been challenged by Zyuganov to a televised debate [in 1996](http://edition.cnn.com/WORLD/9606/13/russia.elex/). I wasn't able to find out if Yeltsin ever took on that challenge. So, did he?

Or is essentially the case that no incumbent of the Russian presidency (who stood for re-election) ever took on [televised] televised debates with his opponents? (Medvedev didn't stand for re-election [insofar].)

Comment: To my knowledge he didn't participate in debates. But  it must be kept in mind that Zyuganov snd communists were viewed in Russia as Jean-Marie Lepen and la Front national in France - in the sense that a debate would legitimize them.

Comment: Yeltsin didn't participate in the 1991 Presidential debates either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it doesn't seem so. On Zyuganov's invitation in particular, Klebnikov's *Godfather of the Kremlin: Life and Times of Boris Berezovsky* states that "Yeltsin immediately rejected [Zyuganov's offer of a debate], fearing a spontaneous debate on Russia's decline". He cites a *Moscow Times* article of [May 12th, 1996](https://www.themoscowtimes.com/archive/zyuganov-seeks-tv-debate-yeltsin-sends-refusal), which reads:

> On Friday, the Communist Party's press service disseminated a letter
> sent from Zyuganov to Yeltsin, dated Wednesday, in which the Communist
> leader called on the president to meet on live television for an "open
> discussion, without aides and consultants."
>
> Zyuganov proposed that each candidate would give his views "on the
> main problems of the country, the paths of its development, the means
> of bringing Russia out of its current dangerous condition." Such a
> meeting, wrote Zyuganov, would help citizens to "make their choice
> independently in this decisive moment."
>
> Yeltsin, however, has apparently rejected Zyuganov's invitation.
> Izvestia, in its Sunday edition, quoted the president as answering: "I
> was a communist for 30 years and heard so much of that demagogy that
> today, given my democratic world view, I can no longer endure that
> demagogy."

It does not appear that Yeltsin took part in any formal debates with any other candidates.