# Why are televised debates seen as essential for free democracies?

Tags: debate

A couple of questions were recently posted about this subject in the context of Russia: [Did Yeltsin participate in formal debates against other candidates for the Russian presidency?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/84743/did-yeltsin-participate-in-formal-debates-against-other-candidates-for-the-russi)

[Is there any precedent of the Russian president skipping a debate during the presidential elections?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/84728/is-there-any-precedent-of-the-russian-president-skipping-a-debate-during-the-pre)

The (unstated) implication of the questions is that participation in debates is essential for democracy to function properly. But why is this the case? The Presidents job does not involve going around debating people on live TV so this is a poor measure of their future performance. CEOs of major corporations aren’t picked based off their debate performance so this is clearly not a standard for other areas of executive selection.

So what’s so special about debates? Why does it matter if a candidate participates in them?

Comment: You seem to be referring specifically to live televised debates? If so, you might want to edit the title accordingly.

Comment: You might want to cite even one person who has ever claimed that "participation in [televised] debates is essential for democracy to function properly". The two questions you linked to were simply questions of fact and (contrary to your claim) made no such "(unstated) implication".

Comment: In the 90-s and early 00-s, Russia was definitely a TV realm and if it wasn't televised, it simply wasn't. Pelevin's "Generation П" explores the phenomenon.

Comment: "So what’s so special about debates?" There is a long standing culture around debates. Maybe somebody has also written about the merits of them. This question could show more research in this direction, I think. Maybe the question is then answered relatively easy. To me the appeal of video is that it makes me feel a bit as if I was there and the appeal of debates is that they give me a judgement on character. It almost looks too trivial to write that down as an answer.

Comment: @alamar My interpretation of that book was that everything on TV is fake and special agents were necessary to convince people it was real :-)

Comment: [In the UK](https://commonslibrary.parliament.uk/research-briefings/sn05241/), prime ministerial debates are very haphazard. There were none before 2010. In 2017 the Conservative leader Theresa May refused to participate; in other years the format has varied.

Comment: Debates are important, but democracy was around for a long time before television was invented. There are reasonable alternatives.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Televised debates are neither "essential" nor "special" in a democracy.

In a Presidential system, where theoretically anyone can stand for the Presidential elections, televised debates can provide a uniform platform to all the contestants to present their political visions and ideas for the country. Incumbent Presidents however may feel no need to participate in such debates as the electorate already knows about their political ideas and policies. But if their policies are being criticised publicly by other candidates, they could indeed use this is an opportunity to defend it. Thus, televised debates can add to the democratic discourse in such systems.

In a Parliamentary system, where the Prime Minister is elected indirectly by those having a majority in the legislature, the political visions and ideas of the Prime Minister will be bound to the political ideology of the party they represent and / or have majority. Since the political parties are an important political institute in such systems, leaders of the party (the potential candidates for Prime Ministership) have an advantage that voters already know about their political ideology by virtue of the political party they belong to. And political parties prepare manifestos that outline their future policies and disseminate it to the public. The media does discuss these, and sometimes have debates by inviting *party representatives*. Moreover, in larger democracies like India, 100's of political parties participate in the elections. Thus, it isn't practical to hold any meaningful debates with so many players.

However, an important idea of a democracy is that elected representatives are answerable to the public. So if a leader, like PM Narendra Modi of India, never organises a Press Conference in 9+ years of being in power, it can be rightly construed of him being scared to face scrutiny and / or of having undemocratic authoritarian tendencies. Similarly Putin refusing to attend television debates (if they are a standard feature of Russian democracy) may also suggest an authoritarian tendency that is generally considered incompatible with democratic values.

Answer (score 4):

TV debates provide a way to see politicians interact and challenge each other's policies directly, how they carry themselves and gauge how well they can think.

Much of the other forms of campaigning are uni-directional and not necessarily all that challenging.  When candidate X says on the campaign trail that he'd "deport all immigrants", that does not give much ground to challenge whether it would be a good policy.  The crowd can generally be expected to be pro-X and in any case a rally is not a Q&A forum.

When candidate Y says on a network interview that she would "amnesty all immigrants", the same mechanism fires in a different way.  The interviewer may be throwing softball, the format may be agreed upon in advance.  Again, pitfalls in that policy may not be sufficiently thrown into light.  And, by now most networks are watched by one side's supporters rather than the other.

Even later press critical coverage of a candidate policy statements lack both the immediacy and the need to respond:  the candidate can ignore the questions entirely unless their campaign team sees a need to respond.

In a debate format - TV or not, but we're long past radio at this point - this comforting ease drops away:  the candidates will have to convince the larger electorate - their side's, their opponent's, plus undecideds are watching - that their opponent's concerns about their policies are unfounded and that these are workable, no-nonsense, not-just-campaign promises.  Their opponent has a vested interest in challenging them on every shaky bit, not giving them a pass.  To go back to my example, past the soundbites and the spin, how solid are X and Y's policies with regards to immigrants? Are they workable?  Costly?  Principled?  Geared towards their political "base" and not relevant to the average citizen?

You, the viewer, get to form your opinion largely without the - possible - filter of news coverage that favors one side over the other, in a non-scripted environment.

A debate may also allow viewers to gauge the charisma and capability to convince of a future leader.  That matters in itself:  like them or not, Reagan's policies got implemented because he was considered "The Great Communicator".  That contrasts to - perhaps - better-intentioned and better briefed leaders that struggle to manage policy because they lack charisma.

And poor Nixon lost his first debate because he appeared shifty and untrustworthy.  Which wasn't all that far off.

Granted, as you look at its website, [Leaders’ Debates Commission](https://www.debates-debats.ca/en/why-debates-matter/), the following is *far* from neutral, but it still does a good job conveying the "pro" side for debates:

> Debates play an essential role in Canada’s democracy. They give you a chance to see the character, temperament, and unscripted approaches of leaders seeking to be Canada’s Prime Minister.

> Making an informed decision is part of a thriving democracy. But it’s difficult to make an informed decision; people are busy, and it’s hard to know what information to trust. A live debate is a trusted source of information, because it’s one of the **very few times during an election campaign that you can hear directly from leaders – unedited and unfiltered**.

> You’ll see leaders together in one place, live on stage, answering questions and challenging each other’s ideas and opinions. This will help you make your own decision about the issues that matter to you. It is also an opportunity to learn about issues that matter to other Canadians, and **be exposed to views that are different from your own, and those around you. It’s a window into the world of others.**

Are they "essential"?  Possibly not, but they are far from negligible and the reasons for refusing to participate in debates is a factor to consider when assessing a candidate.

p.s. The specific election system doesn't matter all that much - Canada uses a parliamentary system yet airs debates between party leaders, much as the US does with POTUS wannabees.

p.p.s.  This importance I attribute to debates *is* an opinion and apparently not a universally held one.  But it is a point of view shared by at least some experts in the field:

[What factors explain the broadcasting of televised election debates? Empirical evidence from Germany](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/02673231221123201)

> Televised election debates are considered as the most important single campaign event.

[The Television Debates: A Revolution That Deserves a Future on JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2747223)

p.p.p.s

All the same, one also has to remember that debating skill is not a foolproof indicator of good leadership by itself and expecting debates to magically "solve" democracy is unrealistic.  Consider how different the world would be now if one of two participants in a certain set of debates in 2016 had been wittier, more likable and less wooden.  Yet, a sharper tongue does not, by itself, a good leader make.

Answer (score 1):

Because official programs of many politicians and their parties are mostly an unreadable mess. They simply promise heaven for everyone without giving too much details how exactly this is achieved and what would be the drawbacks.

Somebody needs to ask them these questions. The debate with opponent is a way to reveal more exact plans and their robustness.

The programs are intentionally foggy to make them to look acceptable for as many people as possible. However, when there are some very obvious actions to take like ending a war the program alone may be enough.

Comment: When the state controls the debates as well it doesn't provide any information.

Comment: @JoeW it says "free democracies" in the question.

Comment: The question is referring to debates in Russia and I would argue that any debates in Russia are controlled by the state. Also you can easily switch the state with party and still have the same thing where the debate only reveals what they want to be.