Is the Presidential Debate mandatory in the United States?
President Joe Biden botched his shot at re-election following the CNN presidential debate that took place on the 27th of June with his weak performance against former president Donald Trump.
Is the presidential debate something mandatory in the process of presidential election in the United States?
If not, Why did Biden not avoid the CNN presidential debate altogether knowing he was going to appear weak and not perform well?

"President Joe Biden botched his shot at re-election[...]" That's quite a premature statement to make, given that the election has not occurred yet. It might also be worth noting that polling averages have changed relatively little since the debate, with both major candidates' support being around the same level as the last few months; indeed, there are points that Biden's support has been lower and Trump's higher.

@Obie2.0: Members of his own party are urging him to drop out of race and their count is rising. This alone has one of the biggest impacts on voters. How is that not botching his shot at re-election?

Setting aside the lack of any demonstrated impact even on polling, let alone actual voting, the problem is that you can't botch something until it fails, and the election has not happened yet.

@Obie2.0: Related Joe Biden Is FINISHED

Related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/84758/why-are-televised-debates-seen-as-essential-for-free-democracies

Edited the question to focus on the general case without discussing actual events which might or might not be biased. Also, the question could show more research. For example search if presidential debates happened all the times in the US. What happened before television was invented?

That makes the accepted answer look like it mentions Biden for no apparent reason. reverting...@NoDataDumpNoContribution

No, the presidential debate is not mandatory. The televized live debates are merely a tradition.
The first such debate series was in 1960 (John F. Kennedy vs. Richard Nixon). In the following three presidential elections, there were no such public debates directly between the two major presidential candidates (Lyndon B. Johnson vs. Barry Goldwater,  Richard Nixon vs. Hubert Humphrey, Richard Nixon vs. George McGovern). Then Jimmy Carter and Gerald Ford revived the idea in 1976, and since then these debates became a tradition and were done a few months before every presidential election.
Why exactly Biden agreed to debate Trump is mere speculation. Maybe he anticipated that he would be in better shape? Maybe he feared that avoiding such an event would create even worse speculations about his physical and mental health? Maybe he felt that the tradition is now so entrenched in the public mind that he felt it was expected of him to participate? Who knows...
It's also relevant to note that this election's presidential debate was a lot earlier in the election year than usual. In the past elections, these debates were in September and October, not in June.

As Biden basically asked for the debate and made Trump accept or look weak, it's likely that was either a bluff or he genuinely thought he'd be in a better shape and could continue where he left of 2020 where he apparently won those debates: https://www.politico.com/newsletters/west-wing-playbook/2024/05/15/why-biden-ditched-the-debate-commission-00158202  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_United_States_presidential_debates

There was almost certainly going to be a debate. What was special about this one was that it was earlier than usual (before the party conventions, so neither candidate had been officially nominated). And it was arranged by the candidates themselves, rather than the Commission on Presidential Debates.

This answer could be improved by going into detail on how the debates are set up. In particular, there are more than two candidates, even though only the Democrat and Republican candidates have a serious chance of being elected. I am sure third party candidates would be delighted to debate, but they are never invited.
